# VSFTPD - Linux (CentOS 5) - Making a single dir FTP root

Tags: centos5, ftp, user-accounts

I have a VPS running CentOS5 with Apache 2.2 and mySQL, as well as VSFTPD for ftp. The user `liam` is a system user.

I want to make the `/home/html` directory the ftp root for the `liam` user, so that when the `liam` user logs in via an ftp client, he sees only the contents of the `/home/html` directory.

How could I do this?

Comment: Is 'liam' a system account or are you using vsFTPd's virtual users?

Comment: A system account

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you'll have to make the `/home/html` directory the home directory of the user `liam`. To do this, execute the following as root:

> `#` usermod -d /home/html liam

You then need to set `chroot_local_user=YES` in the vsftpd config file.

There is a security aspect to using this setting, as described in [this serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/362619/why-is-the-chroot-local-user-of-vsftpd-insecure).

Comment: +1 for adding the home dir. I guess that is what I get for trying to answer this on my phone.

Comment: i will +1 yours if i get my points, because u gave the half of it :]

Answer (score 1):

If liam is a system account you can enable ch_root to jail the user in the home directory. In your vstpd.conf just change the following lines:

chroot_local_user=YES